# Restore deleted system

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-system, system

I have formatted the system using twrp now I can't flash the stock rom on my galaxy s3 sprint. I am getting the `file_getprop: failed to stat "system/build.prop" status 7` every time I try to flash the stock rom.
Is there any possible fix for this problem.

Comment: What **exactly** did you do? "Formatted the system" is too vague.

Comment: @DanHulme I had wapped the system using twrp and now I am getting this message everytime I flash the rom
file_getprop: failed to stat "system/build.prop"

Comment: Error "status 7" usually means you are trying to flash a ROM intended for a different phone model.  What is your phone's exact model number, and which exact ROM are you trying to flash?

Comment: @Chahk you can check my answer :)

Comment: If you were sure that you had a correct ROM version, you could have easily avoided having to Odin back to stock by removing the first "assert" line in the updater script.  I'll post the instructions as a separate answer, for completeness sake.

Comment: @Chahk That will be useful for others but for me I have lost all my data by formatting the whole system so flashing is the only possible way for me I think.

Comment: See my answer. It should work even if you format `/system` partition. You can test by taking a NANDroid backup, formatting /system, modifying the ZIP as described, and flashing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that I have faced was caused by trying to install update of android 4.4.2 for my galaxy s3 while the update requires the previous version which is MK3 (android 4.3). As I mentioned in the question, I have formatted and deleted the whole system that's why `status 7` error showed up because `"system/build.prop"` was already deleted. The only possible solution I made was downloading and flashing the stock rom from [the official site](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/) using od3n software.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the "status 7" error means that the update is designed for a different phone model (could be a completely different phone, or just slightly different variant of the same device.)

This check is performed against the existing `build.prop` file that resides in `/system` partition.  Now since the file was missing due to you having formatted the phone, you are stuck in a "catch-22" situation.  The work-around is to manually remove the above mentioned check.

1. Open the ROM's ZIP file in your favorite archive program (WinZip, 7-Zip, etc.)
2. Within the ZIP, navigate to `META-INF\com\google\android\` folder, and extract only the file named "`updater-script`".
3. Open this file in a text editor.  It's important to use an advanced editor that will not modify the Unix line endings on the file when you save it.  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/), or [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/) are good choices, while Windows' built-in Notepad or WordPad are not recommended.
4. In the `updater-script` file, delete the first statement that begins with "`assert(...`".  This statement may span several lines, so delete all of them.  E.g. for Galaxy S3 it looks like so:

   > assert(getprop("ro.product.device") == "m0" ||
   >   getprop("ro.build.product") == "m0" || 
   >     getprop("ro.product.device") == "i9300" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "i9300" ||
   >     getprop("ro.product.device") == "GT-I9300" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "GT-I9300" || abort("This package is for \"m0,i9300,GT-I9300\" devices; this is a \"" +
   >   getprop("ro.product.device") + "\"."););
5. Add your edited `updater-script` file back into the ZIP file, overwriting the original in the same location.  Depending on the archiving software you are using, it may be as simple as dragging and dropping it in.

Now you should be able to flash the modified ZIP file without it erroring out for model number mismatch.

Note that these "assert" statements are there for your own protection. You should remove them **only** if you are **absolutely certain** that the ZIP file you downloaded matches your phone's model number.  Flashing a ROM made for a different phone (even if it's just a slightly different variant such as AT&T Galaxy S3 Vs. Verizon Galaxy S3) may render your phone inoperable.

Comment: Good answer @chahk actually I have done that but it didn't work. This answer would work for roms like CM but not for the stock update that requires a previous version on a formatted system partition.